# What is returned after using *[]

Tags: python, format

I am trying to learn about `*` in python and encountered this problem, when I do:

```
print(*["John", 20])
```

I get following output:

```
John 20
```

I want to use it here and I know that this works:

```
print("My name is {0}, I am {1} lat".format(*["John", 20]))
```

But I don't understand how this works, as an argument of format I need: `format("John", 20)`, not `format("John" 20)`. Why in print statement I do not see this comma?

Comment: The keyword to google you are looking for is "unpack operator", https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480?gi=1e634c5f4fcd

Comment: Note that it's not really an operator in the sense that `*["John", 20]` is not an *expression* that evaluates to a single value. Rather, it's part of various syntactic constructers (here, function call syntax), and it's meaning is to simply provide one argument per list element. Simply put, `print(*["John", 20])` and `print("John", 20)` are equivalent.  It's the call to `print`, not the syntax, that outputs `John` and `20` separated by a single space.